# Extracting 2-letter capital substrings from table column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have an SQL table on users where particular accounts are tagged with country code (2 letter words in uppercase) while other substrings in the tags (all separated by commas) are either in lowercase or more than 2 letters long.

In user table
Eg:

```
id               User_tags
1                alu,US,ATD
2                GB,xx
3                ol,tuds,FR
```

Users 1,2 and 3 are tagged to countries US, GB and FR and I need to extract them from the user_tags column. I understand that regex functions are needed but I am not able to make them work in an SQL query.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items - it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: Use app code (PHP, Java, etc) to locate 2-cap-letter tags.  SQL, if possible, is very clumsy.  Next time, don't hide them this way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a country code ref table and join to using the below. I don’t have sqlserver open, so unable to double check syntax , but it should work.

```
Select * 
From yourtable y left join refcountry r
On charindex (r.code+’,’,y.string+’,’)>0
```

Note this might be slow for a large dataset

If not sqlserver find the equiv function for charindex in your rdbms